# LFR Benchmark versus Stochastic Block Model

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, graph-theory

Can someone help me to understand the difference between LFR benchmark and Stochastic Block Model. I'm trying to compare community detection algorithms on artificial and real data sets and in artificial part I don't know which benchmark generator is more reasonable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LFR model was designed to reproduce certain topological properties observed in real-world networks: the size of the communities is power-law distributed, and so is the node degree. A parameter called the mixing coefficient allows controlling the average proportion of neighbors a node has in other communities.

The stochastic block model is more general, in the sense it can be used to produce other forms of networks (eg. multipartite or core-periphery instead of community structure). The user specifies the density of links between communities (resp. inside them) for each pair of communities (resp. each community). The size of the communities is not forced to be power-law distributed. You do not directly control the degree distribution.

The LFR model is supposed to be more realistic, meaning it was defined to mimic features observed in certain real-world networks. It was designed to generate benchmarks for community detection. By comparison, the block model was first used in sociology as a way of describing some hypothesis regarding the structure of a real-world network. More recently, the stochastic block model was used to obtain analytical results on the community detection problem and on some resolution methods for this problem (eg. to identify the parameter bounds for which one method can theoreticall find the exact partition).

Personnally, I have used LFR in my work when I needed to perform some empirical comparison of community detection algorithms.

Comment: Thank you dear Mr. Labatut.
Honestly I was waiting response only from you.
I read your works and it was a great explanation